# MSMQ Dead Letter Queue Message Recovery

Tags: msmq, biztalk, biztalk-2009

I'm working on a BizTalk application that sends messages to a Transactional MSMQ location. If it is unable to write to the Queue, the message gets sent to the Dead Letter Queue on the BizTalk server. Is there a better way to handle this? I would prefer the message to suspend so we would get notification from BizTalk360. If it is not possible to suspend the message, and the message must go to the Dead Letter Queue, how can I recover the message once the issue that prevented writing to the Queue is corrected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the best way that I have found to accomplish this is a bit of a hack in my opinion, but it works. I am setting up a receive port/location listening to the Dead Letter Queue at DIRECT=.\SYSTEM$;DEADXACT. I also added an orchestration that listens for messages coming from that receive port and immediately throws an exception suspending the message allowing BizTalk360 to send me notification that there is an issue.